# Win XP - Disable highlighting when 'single-click to open an item' is enabled

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I have 'single-click to open an item' enabled on my XP machine which underlines the item name and highlights the icon on hover-over. I don't mind the underlining but is there a way to disable the highlighting? Maybe a registry tweak?

Comment: I actually don't know that it's possible - the "select on hover" behavior is necessary when it's single-click-to-open, because otherwise, how would you select something without opening?

Comment: @Rilgon: The behavior I am looking for is same as when hovering your mouse over a web link. The link usually gets underlined, selecting it, then you single-click and it goes.

Comment: Correct, but anything "selected" in Windows Explorer is highlighted. That's the nature of item selection.